# I changed the background in login screen and now I can not log in

Tags: login, 20.04, login-screen, recovery-mode, editing

I Changed the background screen and when I tried to login it displays a error message.

I followed these steps.  [vitux.com/how-to-change-login-lock-screen-background-in-ubuntu](https://vitux.com/how-to-change-login-lock-screen-background-in-ubuntu)

edited using text editor.

```
lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///[fileLocation/filename.png]);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear in your post what error message is displayed.

Comment: Have you replaced the [fileLocation/filename.png] with your filename ? Is your filename valid ? and please post the error details you've mentioned.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.